# Accelerate the retrieval time for Entity data

Tags: performance-tuning, curated-data, geography, entity, caching

I like to use Mathematica to answer questions related to cities such as how many cities in the United States have a population greater than 100,000 and what the distribution of them would look like on a map of the continental US.

I have run into an issue downloading the values of all 175,000 cities every time I query `CityData` or `Entity` of type `City`. It often takes 10 to 30 minutes for one line of code to run, such as:

```
citiespopulationbiggerthanhundredthousand = 
 EntityList[
  FilteredEntityClass["City", 
   EntityFunction[c, c["Population"] >= Quantity[100000, "People"]]]]
```

I am wondering if there is a way to reduce the wait time using `EntityPrefetch`, caching, or preloading the data.
I have preloaded the data for `CityData` but when I ran the above code it had to re-download all.
I have also tried using `EntityPrefetch` for `CityData`.
I have found that running RebuildPacletData[] caches the data for offline use.
I also would like to extend this to other types of entities, such as "Aircraft" or "Countries".

Comment: This Wolfram support article discusses how to pre-download some material in paclets, which should include `CityData`: https://support.wolfram.com/12436.

Comment: Also see: [How to keep downloaded curated data](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/78954/27951) and [Make it fast to answer lots of similar Entity questions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/213154/27951).

Comment: I do not have any experience with `FilteredEntityClass`, not sure how your expression is different from ```EntityList@ EntityClass["City", {"Population" -> GreaterThan[Quantity[100000, "People"]]}]``` which is much faster for me